# Foreign key support in SQLite3 C++ ver.3.25.3

Tags: sqlite

**EDIT**

That worked:

```
std::string tab_B = R"(
CREATE TABLE B (
            b        INT      NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY,
            bb       INT      NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY(b) REFERENCES A(a)
     );
 )";
```

Pragma and config were not needed

**END OF EDIT**

I've tried pragma way:

```
std::string fk_on = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;";
sqlite3_exec(DB, fk_on.c_str(), NULL, 0, &messaggeError);
```

and config one:

```
sqlite3_db_config(DB, SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_FKEY, 1, &fkeyConstraintsEnabled);
```

Pragma gives me nothing, fkeyConstraintsEnabled gives 1.
What I am trying to do is to create B table:

```
std::string tab_A = R"(
CREATE TABLE A (
           a        INT      NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY
     );
)";

std::string tab_B = R"(
CREATE TABLE B (
           b        INT      NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY,
           bb       INT      NOT NULL   FOREIGN_KEY REFERENCES A(a)
     );
)";
```

Comment: then accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 std::string tab_A = R"(
 CREATE TABLE A (
             a        INT      NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY
      );
 )";

 std::string tab_B = R"(
 CREATE TABLE B (
            b        INT      NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY,
            bb       INT      NOT NULL ,  FOREIGN_KEY(bb)      REFERENCES A(a)
     );
 )";
```

That's how it's done according to the sqlite documentation. This is, btw, a sqlite problem not a c++ one.

Comment: Drop the tables and use what I have in the answer and try it please. I had to make an edit on it to correct a missing comma issue when I first posted it. It's also identical to what the tutorial I linked you has.